# Text with different size to be on same line in a div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align my text to be on single line. I tried everything vertical-align: middle, vertical-align: bottom.. Please help me :
http://jsfiddle.net/2wDEw/

My simple example looks like that :

```
                <div class="logo spanHalf"><a href="#"> My site </a></div>
                <nav id="menu" class="spanHalf">
                    <li><a href="#">Fetured</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Latest Posts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
                </nav>
```

And my styling :

```
#menu {
    float : right;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

#menu li{
    padding : 10px;
    display:inline;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

#menu a, .logo a {
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    color: black;
    font-weight:bold;
}

#menu a:hover, .logo a:hover {
    color: red;
}

.logo {
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    font-size : 28px;
}
```

Desired result :

MY SITE                                                    FETURED LATEST POSTS CONTACTS

Comment: in the JSFiddle you give all the elements appear in one line..

Comment: I mean all the text to be aligned on single line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give same `line-height` to both the elements.

```
#menu, .row{
    line-height: 40px; /* change this value as needed */
}
```

Also change your HTML as mentioned by John Smith.

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2wDEw/4/)

Answer (score 2):

but your example is invalid html, li´s must be nested in ul or ol use span istead, this also is your problem, because for li´s the clients browser calculates some padding to make it look like a list even if theres no stylesheet, unless you override it

http://jsfiddle.net/2wDEw/2/

```
                <nav id="menu" class="spanHalf">
                    <span><a href="#">Fetured</a></span>
                    <span><a href="#">Latest Posts</a></span>
                    <span><a href="#">Contacts</a></span>
                </nav>
```

Comment: Thanks I change nav to ul and remove their class = spanHalf and everything is fine thanks :)